# How to extract only rows that contain fields in a given list?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider I have 2 tables One `User`

| userId | userName |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | user1 |
| 124 | user2 |

and the other `Items`

| userId | itemName |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | "item1" |
| 123 | "item2" |
| 124 | "item1" |

Is there a way to get a list of all users who have all the items in a given list `(say ["item1","item2"])` i.e in this case only user - 123 is a valid response. the below would be the expected response in this case

| userId | userName |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | user1 |

Right now I am thinking of pulling in data using `in ("item1","item2")`  and then processing it in memory.
I am looking for a way to accomplish this using a query.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result using the same format.

Comment: Do you want those users who have **exactly** those two items? Or _at least_ those two items?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select u.userId,u.userName
from Users u 
inner join ( select userId
             from Items
             where itemName in ('item1','item2')
             group by userId
             having count(itemName)=2
            ) as i  on u.userId=i.userId;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/168

Subquery returns only the `userId` from  `Items` table which have both itemName.

Comment: Note that the dreaded backticks are invalid in Postgres and standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *.u from
user u 
inner join (select * from item where item ='item1') a on a.id=u.id --they have item1
inner join (select * from item where item ='item2') b on b.id=a.id --they have item2
;
```

It takes only user that have both,  [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a915228/1)

After your explanation

```
select count(*), u.id from
user u 
inner join (select * from item where item in ('item1','item2')) a on  a.id=u.id
having count(*)>1
```

Comment: This works well for 2 items but what if I have a  list of Items. I will edit the question.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought it was this specific case. Can we also say in Items you never have duplicates?

Comment: No as in the example each row in the User table can have multiple mapped rows in the Items table and these will be different for a given user but across multiple users the items may repeat, like "item1" here repeats.

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.* from User u
  join (select userId from Items where itemName='item1' 
  intersect
  select userId from Items where itemName='item2') sub 
on u.userId=sub.userId;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `EXISTS` with a `HAVING` will get you that.

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM Users AS usr
> WHERE EXISTS (
>   SELECT 1
>   FROM Items AS itm
>   WHERE itm.userId = usr.userId
>     AND itm.itemName IN ('item1', 'item2')
>   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT itm.itemName) = 2
> );
> ```

| userid | username |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | user1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=213d08b052fc2b02469cf76ed88da24a)*

Answer (score 0):

a with clause and array comparison:(postgres)

```
with base_data as (
select 
userId,
array_agg(itemName) over (partition by userId) as liste
from Items
)
select 
* from base_data
where liste @> array['item1','item2']::varchar[]
```